# How to increase the font size of a big wide table?

Tags: tables, fontsize

Recently I had a major revision from a journal and the reviewer complained that "Table 4 is difficult to read".
The snapshot of the table in PDF version is given below...
Also the latex code for the Table is

```latex
\begin{table*}[h!]
\caption{SRE approaches- at a glance}
\Large
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
\begin{tabular}{lllllcccc}\toprule
 \textbf{SRE approaches} & \textbf{Model/technique adopted} & \textbf{Elicitation technique used} &\textbf{Integration of standards}& \textbf{Size of project} &  \textbf{ Threat modeling } & \textbf{Risk analysis}  & \textbf{Tool support} & \textbf{Industry adoption}   \\
 \midrule
 & Goal – Oriented approach, uses    & Interviewing, existing & - & large  & Yes & No & Yes & No \\
{KAOS}&  anti-models for  modeling   & systems study & & & &  & (Objectiver) &  \\
 & threats & & & & & & & \\[2pt] \hline

{Secure i*} & Agent Oriented approach,  & artefacts analysis, & - & large &  No &  No & Yes & Not reported \\
& uses i* modeling framework & Interviews & & & & & (ST-Tool) & \\ [2pt]  \hline

{Secure Tropos} & Agent oriented approach,  & Constraints analysis & ISO/IEC 17799- & large & No & No & Yes & Not reported   \\
&  uses i* modeling framework  & & & & & & (ST-Tool, SecTro) & \\ [2pt]  \hline

{GBRAM} & goal based approach  & - & - & medium & No & Yes & No & No  \\
& & & & & & & & \\[2pt]   \hline

 & Problem Frame based approach, & - & ISO13335 & medium & No & No & No & No  \\
 {Abuse Frames}&uses constraints for security  & & & & & & & \\
 &goal modelling & & & & & & & \\[2pt]  \hline

{SEPP} & Uses  security patterns, security & - & CC & large & Yes & No & No & No   \\
&problem frames and templates   & & & & & & & \\ [2pt]  \hline

{SREF} & Goal based approach & - & - & large & Yes & No & No & Not reported     \\
& & & & & & & & \\[2pt]   \hline

{CORAS} & Uses security-risk model  & Meeting with the clients & ISO31000 & large & Yes & Yes & Yes & not reported \\
&  inspired by UML & & & & & & (CORAS Tool)& \\[2pt]   \hline

{SREP} & Based on unified process & - & CC &  - & Yes & Yes & No & Not reported \\
& model of  SDLC & & & & & & & \\[2pt] \hline

{Microsoft’s threat } & Based on STRIDE  and DREAD & - & - &  medium & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes   \\
modeling &  methodology & & & & & & (Threat Modeling Tool) &  \\[2pt]   \hline

{CLASP} & Adopts Resource centric & Interviewing/existing   & - & large & Yes & Yes & No & Yes   \\
& methodology & artefacts analysis & & & & & & \\[2pt]   \hline

 & Adopts a Series of prescriptive  & Any & - & - & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
{SQUARE}& steps for eliciting,analyzing  & & & & & & (P-SQUARE, eSQUARE) & \\
&  and categorizing requirements & & & & & & & \\[2pt]   \hline

 & Adopts Multilateral Security  & - & - & large & No & No & No & No \\
{MSRA}&  concepts  and View – point oriented  & & & & & & & \\
&  Requirements Engineering & & & & & & & \\[2pt]  \hline

{SRE methods based } & Adopts and uses agile  & User stories & - & large & Yes & No & No & Yes  \\
on AGILE & methodology  with security & & & & & & & \\[2pt]   \hline

{Secure UML} & Based on UML and Model & - & - & medium & No & No & Yes & No\\
&  based Architecture & & & & & & (Visio-based template) &  \\[2pt]   \hline

 & Based on extension of UML & -  & ISO/IEC 15408, ISO/IEC 27001,& medium & No & No & Yes & No   \\
{UMLsec} & for secure systems development & & ISO/IEC 17799, ISO/IEC 13335, & & & &(CARISMA) & \\
&&& IEEE 830-1998&&&&& \\[2pt]   \hline

 & Based on extension of UML     & Brain-storming &-& small &  Yes & Yes & No & Yes    \\
{Misuse Case}&  use case to model threat   & & & & & & & \\
&  and risks & & & & & & & \\[2pt]  \hline

 & Model oriented framework for    & Any &-& medium(web-based) &  Yes & Yes & No & No    \\
{MOSRE}&   elicitation, analysis and traceability   & & & & & & & \\
&   of security requirements  & & & & & & & \\[2pt]  \hline

 & Iterative process based on & - & ISO/IEC Guide 73, ISO/IEC 27001 & large &  Yes & Yes & No & Not reported    \\
{ISSRM}&  existing risk analysis standards   & & AS/NZS 4360,ISO/IEC 13335-1 & & & & & \\
&  and methods & & & & & & & \\[2pt]  \hline

{Ontology based } & Based on reuse of Security     & ontology & ISO/IEC 27001, ISO/IEC 27002 & small (domain-specific) &  Yes & Yes & Yes & No    \\
 SRE approaches& ontologies   & & & & & &(Protege) & \\
&  & & & & & & & \\[2pt]
\bottomrule

\end{tabular}
%
\label{tab:1}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table*}
```

How to enhance the readability of this table

Comment: welcome to text.se! please extend your code snippet to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}`, document preamble (with relevant packages only), your table and ending with `\end{document}`. page layout is quite essential, that we see, how much space is available to your table..

Comment: on the first sight: your table is to huge that it can be suit to one page and in the same time be readable. you should consider to redesign table. for example, change its orientation to landscape and enable  its break over two page. for example, use `pdflscape`package and its environment `landscape` and instead tabular` use `xltabular` table environment.

Comment: never scale tables `\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}` will just make the font arbitrarily small, You never want to justify text by scaling in that way. replace `lllllcccc` by columns that allow line breaking `p{2cm}` or whatever